# Angular App with PHP rendering {{ }} from database and angular throws error

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, escaping

Basically, a user adds a comment, when we render the page we use PHP not angular to render comment. If a comment has `{{}}` in content angular throws error can't find variable (can't parse).

I did a hack for viewing a comment by finding `{{` and replacing with `<span>{</span>{` but that doesn't work in the `textarea` to edit a comment.

The only way I fixed it was by adding `htmlentities()` but that breaks the WYSIWYG as it starts showing `<p>` tags.

How can I still show the `{{` without JS errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just displayed PHP content inside a script `type="text/template"` and then on edit comment I use jquery `.html` to add to the ckeditor.

Comment: if you use ckeditor you can try : `$scope.text = angular.element("#id").text()`